# What have I done to get flagged by all kinds of CAPTCHAs?

Tags: firefox, internet, captcha

Googles ReCAPTCHA gives me 5 pages of tasks and fails me even though my answers are correct.

Cloudflare CAPTCHA fails me everytime by default.

I'm blocked from sites "protected" by cloudflare.

What have I done to deserve this? I'm using Firefox with standard extensions such as Dark Reader, Tabliss and uBlock Origin. Everything works normally in private mode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You probably didn’t do anything. If you are behind a corporate proxy that likely is the cause.

Comment: If you complete a captcha too quickly, it rejects you. Fill it in, wait 30 seconds, then try & continue.

Comment: Try audio CAPTCHA. I find the visual ones ambiguous (Is that a motorcycle in the rectangle, if it's the riders helmet???).

Comment: Try disabling some of your extensions. uBlock Origin might be the first suspect.

Comment: CAPTCHA theoretically looks at HOW you move your mouse to click the elements, moreso than WHAT you click. The idea is that humans do things differently to computers. Re uBlock Origin: that's a good plugin, but you may try removing custom filters and refreshing the cache on that plugin. You should also clear your browser cache and cookies as well, just as a general principle of resolving web issues.